# Can't remove an image in a concrete5 page

Tags: concrete5

I need to replace an image on my homepage:

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2761955/f3fee6769d40490564376bbec112f639

When I go into the page editor and try to edit remove or change the image, nothing happens.

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2762067/aab918e29752a4cd7127790c66e63c59

I read about a Chrome bug that say may cause this but I get the same results in Firefox.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
Delete the block in question and add a new one with the desired image.